# Coldfusion error handling

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create some custom error pages that email our developers that there has been an 404 or 500 error in coldfusion. Also it would be helpful if within the email it gives the error variables.

I have set up a error page in coldfusion and have pointed IIS(7) at it.

Also in my application.cfm file I am declaring the following:

```
<cferror type="exception" template="#name#">
<cferror type="request" template="#name#"> 
<cferror type="validation" template="#name#"> 
<cferror type="monitor" template="#name#">
```

My problem is that within the error file I cannot include any CF calls, CF appears to stripe them out.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

*As per Travis' comments below - while the use of the `cferror` tag is still supported it is recommended to convert from Application.cfm to Application.cfc (if not already) and use the `onError` method instead. All of the restrictions that I have listed below do not apply when using the `onError` method and all CFML functionality is available. [Here is the ColdFusion 9 documentation for the onError method.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d4a.html)*

There is an entire section of the [ColdFusion documentation regarding error handling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffe.html) in detail.  But for your specific question regarding the `cferror` tag you need to realize that there are limitations to what ColdFusion can do when an error occurs and even that depends on the type of error.  Here is an excerpt taken from [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffc.html):

The following table lists the
rules and considerations that apply to error application pages:

**Validation**

- Cannot use CFML tags
- Can use HTML tags
- Can use the `Error.InvalidFields`, `Error.validationHeader`, and `Error.validationFooter` variables by enclosing them with number signs (#)
- Cannot use any other CFML variables

**Request**

- Cannot use CFML tags
- Can use HTML tags
- Can use nine CFML error variables, such as `Error.Diagnostics`, by enclosing them with number signs
- Cannot use other CFML variables

**Exception**

- Can use full CFML syntax, including tags, functions, and variables
- Can use nine standard CFML Error variables and cfcatch variables. Use either `Error` or `cferror` as the prefix for both types of variables
- Can use other application-defined CFML variables
- To display any CFML variable, use the cfoutput tag

Excerpt taken from [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d29.html) regarding the available error variables for each exception type:

**Validation only**

```
    error.validationHeader  Validation message header text.
    error.invalidFields     Unordered list of validation errors.
    error.validationFooter  Validation message footer text.
```

**Request and Exception**

```
    error.diagnostics       Detailed error diagnostics from ColdFusion.
    error.mailTo            E-mail address (same as value in cferror.MailTo).
    error.dateTime          Date and time when error occurred.
    error.browser           Browser that was running when error occurred.
    error.remoteAddress     IP address of remote client.
    error.HTTPReferer       Page from which client accessed link to page where error occurred.
    error.template          Page executing when error occurred.
    error.generatedContent  The content generated by the page up to the point where the error occurred.
    error.queryString       URL query string of client's request.
```

**Exception only**

```
    error.message           Error message associated with the exception.
    error.rootCause         The root cause of the exception. This structure contains the information that is returned by a cfcatch tag.
                            For example, for a database exception, the SQL statement that caused the error is in the error.RootCause.Sql variable.
                            For Java exceptions, this variable contains the Java servlet exception reported by the JVM as the cause of the "root cause" of the exception.
    error.tagContext        Array of structures containing information for each tag in the tag stack. The tag stack consists of each tag that is currently open.
    error.type              Exception type.
```

*Note: If type = "exception", you can substitute the prefix cferror for Error; for example, cferror.diagnostics, cferror.mailTo, or cferror.dateTime.*

Comment: I had to vote this down because all the detailed information you provided uses cferror which is still acceptable but would be much better to use the onerror function in your application.cfc.  You are not restricted by any of these things and don't have to worry about the type.  In onError you can do any processing with any tags or script and have full access to every variable scope as if it were a normal request.

Comment: No problem - I agree with you.  I only posted this as the OP was asking about `cferror` specifically. Which I can only assume means that he is still using `Application.cfm` as well.  I thought it would be easier to just answer this question then bring about an entire new architecture for the OP. I believe this explains why 'CF appears to strip them out' to the OP.  Still, your point is valid.

Comment: Valid assumption. You can actually use cferror in application.cfc and with the little effort it takes to convert to application.cfc, being on cf9, it is long overdue

Comment: I attempted to remove the down vote because it will likely solve his problem despite the unfavorable tag

Comment: Thanks @Travis.  I will add a note at the beginning of this answer that it is better/preferable to use the `onError` function of `Application.cfc` instead.

Comment: My phone submitted the comment before I was ready.  I meant to say the answer needs to be edited before I can change my vote. Adding a note to that effect would allow me to do that. thanks!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the onRequest handler is required to access any of the page variables in onError

Comment: I added reference and a link to the documentation for the `onError` method which explains that.  Thanks again @Travis .

Answer (score 1):

Does your error file have a .cfm extension?

Also, if you send an e-mail with every 404, you could open yourself up to a mail bomb attack. You would probably be better adding something like Google Analytics to check for 404s. The 500 error could mean a number of things have gone wrong, so CF probably wouldn't sent an e-mail anyhow.

Comment: I won't have the custom page emailing for 400 errors just 500 errors. The file is a .cfm file. The error page does display it just strippes out any cf calls which is annoying because I want to be able to use cf mail etc within the file.

Answer (score 1):

using a template is best precise for this reason for example... dbc.cfm. 
write mail sending code in dbc.cfm.

```
<cftry>
        <cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
            SELECT m.price
            FROM productvendorsmap m
            WHERE m.productid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ProductId#">
            AND m.vendorid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#VendorIdd#">
        </CFQUERY>
        <cfcatch type="Database">
            **<cfinclude template="dbc.cfm">**
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
```