# How to show a custom error page in ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion

I want to know that how to show a custom error cfm page when an error occurred.

I wrote the below lines in application.cfm

```html
<cferror type="request" template="ErrorPage.cfm"/>
<cferror type="exception" template="ErrorPage.cfm"/>
<cferror type="validation" template="ErrorPage.cfm"/>
```

But this code can not handle the TemplateNotFound exception, I know that there is a setting in the ColdFusion server to specify the path for our custom missing template handler and site wide error handler. But i don't want this because this will affect all of my applications running under the server.

I also used onMissingTemplate function in application.cfm but that also didn't work.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest abandoning the practice of using `application.cfm` and use `application.cfc` instead.  You would then place your exception handling code (including TemplateNotFound) in the `OnError()` event.

Comment: @user9263373 When I read down and saw `Application.cfm`, my first suggestion was to ditch it and go with the `.cfc` version. You beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Also, here's a good post to read regarding someone trying to something similar to what you're trying.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838468/coldfusion-error-handling

Comment: You can try to add a page in ColdFusion Administrator CFAdmin -> Settings ->Missing Template Handler. OR try setting an error page in IIS if this needs to be for a single site.

That being said, I would suggest that you upgrade to Application.cfc instead of Application.cfm and `cferror` tags are not really in use now a days.